# Ref array of dropdown different components by id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I have a list of comments, something like this:

[image]

Each one has a dropdown of options which the user can edit or delete any comment.

So, when I open one of the, this display the dropdown:

[image]

The problem is when the user does click in other place of the page, that dropdown should close, but it doesn't... Only close when the user does click in the icon... I want to know how to remove that click event... Not always click the icon to close it.

Here's a little [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/qr66qqxo4) if someone need it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an event listener to keep track of all click event happening on the page. Whenever the event fires, the app decides if the event target is from inside the popover div, if not, it will close the popover.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClickOutsideToClose);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClickOutsideToClose);
  }

  handleClickOutsideToClose = e => {
    let toClose = true;
    this.dropdown.forEach(dropdown => {
      if (dropdown.contains(e.target)) {
        toClose = false;
      }
    });

    if (toClose) {
      this.handleCloseAll();
    }
  };

 handleCloseAll = () => {
    console.log("close all");
    this.dropdown.map(dropdown => {
      dropdown.classList.remove("is-active");
    });
  };
```

Check out the code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jl8q06k955) for a live demo. I've also made some minor changes to your `handleOpenDropdown` function so that only a single dropdown can be opened at a given time.

Hope this helps.